# Error after installing EclipseCoder plugin to run Topcoder Arena

Tags: c++, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-kepler

I tried to install a plugin called EclipseCoder to run Topcoder arena through Eclipse (for c/c++), but it does not work and throws errors. I did following.

1. I installed Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 for C/C++, It was
   working fine for local codes.
2. I added a plugin by going to help -> Install new software, and used
   http://fornwall.net/eclipsecoder/
3. After Installing I opened arena from eclipse and it fetched the
   problem statement and code template correctly but it shows following errors.

[image: It Throws Following Exception]

Also eclipse is unable to resolve any header files generated, it says **Unresolved inclusion: header file name**, It creates a .h file but I think it should create .cpp file (if working for c++).

I followed steps given at http://fornwall.net/eclipsecoder/

Exception Stack Trace is as Follows :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find binary
    at net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.ccsupport.CBinaryLauncher.<init>(CBinaryLauncher.java:71)
    at net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.ccsupport.CCLanguageSupport$1.run(CCLanguageSupport.java:120)
    at net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.util.Utilities$5.run(Utilities.java:284)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find binary
    at net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.ccsupport.CBinaryLauncher.<init>(CBinaryLauncher.java:68)
```

Another Error Message in Error Log : 
**Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".**

And Its Stack Trace is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.ManagedBuildInfo.findExistingDefaultConfiguration(ManagedBuildInfo.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.ManagedBuildInfo.getDefaultConfiguration(ManagedBuildInfo.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.BuilderFactory.createBuilders(BuilderFactory.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ManagedBuilderCorePlugin.createBuilders(ManagedBuilderCorePlugin.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.getRule(CommonBuilder.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: First, open the "Error Log" view and see if the exception is there. If so double click on it and you'll likely get the stacktrace (which you might add to the question).

Comment: You can also look in the '.log' file (in <yourWSPath>/.metadata)...

Comment: Same problem, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Inoryy Still looking for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting - this should now be fixed in version 0.2.6 of the C++ support plug-in available at the update site as of now!